# F to report woth Duncan Post hoc?

Tags: anova, p-value, post-hoc

I am currently writing the session results in a paper. I performed a simple repeated measures anova with two within factors and I got a significant interaction. I perform my Duncan Post Hoc, and I report the p of the significant comparisons.
Do I need to report also the F associated with the p of the Duncan? Because in the program (statistica) that I am using, F is not included in the output.
Thanks,
Chiara

Answer (score 1):

First, since the interaction is significant, I hope you are comparing the means for the *factor combinations*, not the marginal means.

Second, the Duncan method does not control any error rate in and of itself. That error rate is only weakly controlled by virtue of the preceding *F* test. So, yes, you should report the *F* result as well. If you were using the Newman-Keuls or Tukey method, it would not be necessary to report the *F*-test result (or even to do that test).

I have never seen a convincing justification for the Duncan method.